# Are there drawbacks of creating a lot of short-life threads?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

Are there drawbacks if we create a **short-life thread** (200 ms to 1 second) to perform a search task **on every keypress** in a Textbox field?

```
std::wstring query;

void DoTheSearch ()
{
     // 200ms to 1sec long processing that would block the GUI if no dedicated thread 
     // search a database using query variable
}


// main window message loop
case WM_COMMAND:
// ...
    if (wmEvent == EN_CHANGE)
    {
        query = GetTheQueryStringFromTextBox(...);
        DWORD threadID;
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, DoTheSearch, NULL, 0, &threadID); 
        // there will be a lot (for each keypress) of short-life threads often
    }
```

Or should I make only **one thread** for the search (with a `while (True)` idle most of the time, and with `Sleep(10);` inside?).

---

*Note: I've also implemented a "debouncing" feature to avoid as many searches than every keypress, but this is out of the topic here.*

Comment: What you want to do is look up [conditions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)  This will let you have a single thread without a 'sleep'

Comment: I dont think the question is bad, but it contains actually two.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann it also keeps changing

Comment: @UKMonkey I modified to clarify it, because I noticed it was too broad before.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann I modified it to make it simpler.

Comment: Creating a thread is a costly operation. Creating lots of short-lived threads will have diminishing returns, until it finally becomes slower than a single-threaded application doing the same operation. Consider using a thread-pool instead. If thread creation is triggered by user input, it probably doesn't matter much, though, because users are several orders of magnitude slower than code.

Comment: There is overhead for creating a thread. Multi-threaded code is beneficial when the amount of work done per thread is high and the amount of work done outweighs the cost of creating the thread (i.e. multi-threaded code is not always faster).

Comment: @IInspectable if someone writes fast, there would be max 10 threads created by second (when one thread is created, i would kill the previous one because the query string would have changed).

Comment: @crashmstr I don't do a thread to do multithreading things intrisically, but to avoid the GUI / main window to be unrespsonsive during 200 to 1000ms.

Comment: what might throw a spanner in the entire works (regardless of how fast user types) is the non-deterministic execution order of the created threads. Looking up keypress for time t+5 before keypress for time t+1 might (or might not) be ok. If there is UI feedback from the message queue dependent upon the keypress the user might find it a bit disconcerting. Depends on use case of course

Comment: Still, my point remains that creating a thread is relatively expensive, and a short lived thread that does little work is not cost effective.

Comment: for this kind of task the best use working threads pool [`QueueUserWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684957(v=vs.85).aspx) or new pool api [`SubmitThreadpoolWork`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686338(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: There seems to be some disagreement over whether creating and destroying threads is "costly."  OK, but it _has_ a cost.  And it's up to _you_ to consider that cost relative to how much work you expect each thread to do, and how much other work your application needs to do, and how much CPU power is available to do the work.  If _you_ think that the cost of creating and destroying a new thread for each task is too high, then you can mitigate that cost by using a _thread pool_.

Comment: Another solution to consider: (Re-)Start a timer in response to input, and only launch the thread doing the actual work, when the timer expires. This prevents creation and coordination of all those throw-away threads, that are launched in response to transient input changes.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the popular opinion, creating a thread is not that expensive. While I do not have Windows machine to test, but I would imagine thread creation time on modern Windows systems to be within single units of microseconds (as it is on Linux).

So if your design becomes much simpler with a short-lived thread scenario, and threads do not have context to persist, and at any given time you only have one working thread, and they are started not that often (say, every 10 seconds or more) I see no particular reason to bent the design to allow for thread message queuing.

Comment: Given that the question states that it will be done per key press, the assertions 'one working thread' and 'started not that often' are false.

Comment: @UKMonkey, how fast do you type? :D

Comment: With my hands or feet? :P

Comment: @UKMonkey can you suggest (in an answer) a cleaner way? I could start one thread but then how should I wait for a new DoTheSearch message with a `while (true)`? Maybe just a < 10 lines sketch would help a lot :)

Comment: @SergeyA aren't they "anti [fork-bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)" mechanism on Linux or Windows that would create a problem if 10 or 20 new threads arrive in a short time?

Comment: @Basj, depends on your undertanding of 'short time'. Once every ten seconds (as in my answer) is most certainly not the fork bomb.

Comment: How expensive is "that expensive?"  I'll concede that the cost of creating and destroying a thread is trivial compared to the cost of raytracing a multi-megapixel image of some complex 3D scene if you'll concede that the cost of creating and destroying a thread is overwhelming relative to the cost of incrementing a counter.

Comment: Isn't *"I would imagine"* the same as saying *"I guess"*? In other words: A substantial part of your answer is essentially speculation. You should probably do some research on this, and update your proposed answer.